# Pandas reindex datetimeindex keeping existing values

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to add zero values to a Panadas dataframe where data has not been recorded, using an hourly timestamp.

Ie I would like output to be:

```
DataFrame:                      quantity
created_at     
2018-01-21 14:00:00         0              
...
2018-01-22 12:00:00         0
2018-01-22 13:00:00         0
2018-01-22 14:00:00         31
```

In the code below, when I reindex, the value in the quantity column is set to Nan.

How can I keep existing values but add hour time indexes with zero values where they are missing?

```
data = {'date_time': ['2018-01-22 14:47:05.486877'], 
     'quantity': [31]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['date_time', 'quantity']) 
df.index = df['date_time']
del df['date_time'] 
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

#want to sum data by hour
df = df.resample('H').sum()

#set minutes etc to zero for indexing
current_date = datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0,second=0,minute=0)
d2 = current_date - timedelta(hours = 24)
all_times = pd.date_range(d2, current_date, freq = "H")

#ensure index format is exactly same as df (may be unecessary?)
df.index =df.index.map(lambda t: t.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))

#this sets everything to Nan and wipes existing quantity data
df = df.reindex(all_times)
df = df.fillna(0)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need convert datetimes to hours by [`floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) and change range for reindex - e.g. `+- 24 hour`s from current datetime if necessary - it mainly depends of `current_date` and `Datetimeindex`:

```
data = {'date_time': ['2018-01-22 14:47:05.486877'], 
     'quantity': [31]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['date_time', 'quantity']) 
#print (df)


df.date_time = pd.to_datetime(df.date_time)
df = df.set_index('date_time')
df = df.resample('H').sum()

current_date = pd.datetime.now()
print (current_date)
2018-01-22 10:31:37.663110


all_times = pd.date_range(current_date - pd.Timedelta(hours = 24),
                          current_date + pd.Timedelta(hours = 24), freq = "H").floor('H')
#print (all_times)

df = df.reindex(all_times, fill_value=0)
```

---

```
print (df)
                     quantity
2018-01-21 10:00:00         0
2018-01-21 11:00:00         0
2018-01-21 12:00:00         0
2018-01-21 13:00:00         0
2018-01-21 14:00:00         0
2018-01-21 15:00:00         0
2018-01-21 16:00:00         0
2018-01-21 17:00:00         0
2018-01-21 18:00:00         0
2018-01-21 19:00:00         0
2018-01-21 20:00:00         0
2018-01-21 21:00:00         0
2018-01-21 22:00:00         0
2018-01-21 23:00:00         0
2018-01-22 00:00:00         0
2018-01-22 01:00:00         0
2018-01-22 02:00:00         0
2018-01-22 03:00:00         0
2018-01-22 04:00:00         0
2018-01-22 05:00:00         0
2018-01-22 06:00:00         0
2018-01-22 07:00:00         0
2018-01-22 08:00:00         0
2018-01-22 09:00:00         0
2018-01-22 10:00:00         0
2018-01-22 11:00:00         0
2018-01-22 12:00:00         0
2018-01-22 13:00:00         0
2018-01-22 14:00:00        31
2018-01-22 15:00:00         0
2018-01-22 16:00:00         0
2018-01-22 17:00:00         0
2018-01-22 18:00:00         0
2018-01-22 19:00:00         0
2018-01-22 20:00:00         0
2018-01-22 21:00:00         0
2018-01-22 22:00:00         0
2018-01-22 23:00:00         0
2018-01-23 00:00:00         0
2018-01-23 01:00:00         0
2018-01-23 02:00:00         0
2018-01-23 03:00:00         0
2018-01-23 04:00:00         0
2018-01-23 05:00:00         0
2018-01-23 06:00:00         0
2018-01-23 07:00:00         0
2018-01-23 08:00:00         0
2018-01-23 09:00:00         0
2018-01-23 10:00:00         0
```